# String comparsion with different variants

Tags: php, regex

I have strings:

```
$string = 'michelinx-icexi3xl92t';
```

OR

```
$string = 'michelinx-icexi2xl92t';
```

and array

```
$array = array( 0 => 'x-ice', 1 => 'x-icenorth', 2 => 'x-icexi2', 3 => 'x-icexi3');
```

what am i doing is:

```
foreach($array as $key => $arr)
{
    if(strstr($string, $arr)){ 
        //some code here
        break;
    }
}
```

in both cases this code stops when $key == 0;
but i need to stop it when $key == 3 or 2 or maybe another key, which better matches the string

any advices how to do this?

Comment: It stop because it get match on very first array. What is your criteria to get it stop on `$key == 3` ?

Comment: that is the question +)
the problem is - how to change this code

Comment: before break put if statement checking value of `$key == 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code to find **better matched string**:

```
$string = 'michelinx-icexi3xl92t';
$array = array( 0 => 'x-ice', 1 => 'x-icenorth', 2 => 'x-icexi2', 3 => 'x-icexi3');
$matchedStr = "";
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if(strstr($string, $val) && strlen($val) > strlen($matchedStr)) { 
        //some code here
        $matchedStr = $val;
    }
}
echo "matched string is: " . $matchedStr;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
matched string is: x-icexi3
```

Answer (score 3):

Your current code stops after finding the *first* string that matches. From the question, it seems that your requirement is to find the *longest* string that matches. Therefore, if you arrange for the longest string to always appear first you can use your existing code without modification.

So here's how to sort an array of strings by string length descending using a custom sort:

```
$array= array(0 => 'x-ice', 1 => 'x-icenorth', 2 => 'x-icexi2', 3 => 'x-icexi3');
usort($array, function($a, $b) { return strlen($b) - strlen($a); });
```

This method also has the advantage that you don't spend any time searching for results that you are going to throw away later (once you find the first match, you already know it's also the best one) so in most cases it will run faster.

**However, your code also has a bug you must fix:** in the general case you can't test the return value `strstr` like that (it will fail if you search for `"0"`). It will also be faster to use `strpos` instead, like this:

```
if(strpos($arr, $string) !== false){ 
    //some code here
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($array as $key => $arr)
{
    if(strstr($string, $arr)){ 
        //some code here


        if($key == 3)
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: no) imagine that $array has another keys? what if in next call of this code the string will be michelinx-icexi3xl92t

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    foreach($array as $key => $arr)
    {
        if(strstr($string, $arr)){ 
            //some code here
            break;
        }

        if($key == 3) break;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the break if you want to loop though the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution could be, sort descending your array with length of strings i.e.

```
$array = array( 0 => 'x-ice', 1 => 'x-icenorth', 2 => 'x-icexi2', 3 => 'x-icexi3');
```

will become

```
$array = array( 0 => 'x-icenorth', 1 => 'x-icexi2', 2 => 'x-icexi3', 3 => 'x-ice');
```

then do:

```
foreach($array as $key => $arr)
{
    if(strstr($string, $arr)){ 
        //some code here
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to find the most matched string in the array. To do this you can simply do this:

```
$most_matched_pos = 0;
$most_matched_len = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $cur = strlen(strstr($string, $val));
    if($cur > $most_matched_len ) { 
        $most_matched_len = $cur;
        $most_matched_pos = $key;
    }
}

echo "The  most matched is {$array[$most_matched_pos]} ";
```

With your example you have this output:

> The most matched is x-icexi3